# Adding url paramaters to permalink

Tags: wordpress

For example this url `https://www.example.co.uk/product/decking/grade-1-4/`  is a wordpress permalink.  I tried to add url parameters to the link but i get **page_not_found** .

I want `https://www.example.co.uk/product/decking/grade-1-4/&c=5`, where i can use `$_GET['c'];` to get the value of the parameter.

I tried this but not working. This file is in `functions.php`

```
 function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "c"; 
    return $aVars;
    }
 add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

How do i solve.  I want this parameters to be available on any permalink.

Comment: Does it work if you change the `&` in your URL to a `?`

Comment: Yes, got it working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

```
add_filters( 'post_link', 'my_add_qvar', 10, 1);
function my_add_qvar($permalink){
    return add_query_arg('c','c_value',$permalink);
}
```

the code above modify the permalink output